# Facebook Login for Android getting error for the second login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am very new to facebook sdk and currently I am implementing the Facebook login button and it's work very well at the first time login and when I logged-out and try to login again it's give me an error as bellow image. And I am sure with the Key Hash was corrected. Appreciated for your kindly help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this tutorial for integrating facebook sdk in android.
[link 1 for eclipse](http://androidsrc.net/use-facebook-login-android-using-latest-fb-sdk/)

[link 2 for android studio](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-facebook-integration-tutorial)

worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your link. it's really helpful now I success :).